# Method chaining between child and parent classes

Tags: java

So imagine we have the following.

```
public class Animal {
    public Animal walk(){
        // walk
        return this;
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
    public Dog bark(){
        // bark
        return this;
    }
    public Dog scratch(){
        // scratch
        return this;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do this,

```
Dog dog = new Dog()
    .bark()
    .walk() // error: required Dog but provided Animal, and so it can't find the child method.
    .scratch();
```

What are the possible ways to achieve this? And what's the best one (convention)?

Comment: Override the `walk` method in the `Dog` class, like so: `@Override public Dog walk() { super.walk(); return this; }`. Java supports so called "covariant return types".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen at least two approaches.

1. Make `Animal` generic, and use the generic type as return type:

```java
public class Animal<A extends Animal<A>> {
    public A walk(){
        // walk
        return (A) this;
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal<Dog> {
    public Dog bark(){
        // bark
        return this;
    }
    public Dog scratch(){
        // scratch
        return this;
    }
}
```

2. Override the method like Alex R said in his comment.

I prefer option 2, because a) it doesn't require me to use generics when I want just `Animal`, and b) it allows me to extend `Dog` without having to make `Dog` generic too. With some unit tests using reflection I can check that each method is properly overridden.

Comment: Ahhhhh, so there's my problem... I was unsuccessfully trying that generic type approach, not realizing that I was missing the type <Dog> after Animal, in the class declaration.

Anyway, would you still prefer option 2) in case we have many (like seriously, a lot) classes extending the Animal class?

Thank you.

Comment: If there are a lot of classes, then option 2 obviously becomes a lot of work, especially if the number of methods in `Animal` isn't just 1 or 2. If `Animal` is abstract and rarely used directly, then option 1 becomes more interesting.